# how to store multiple form with multiple buttons data on single page using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

This is my form and I don't want to any change or form action and button id:-

```
<form action="store" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_related_product" name="addons_heading" value="<?php if (isset($setting['addons_heading'])){echo htmlentities($setting['addons_heading']);}?>">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="label_quantity" name="quantity" value="<?php if (isset($setting['quantity'])){echo $setting['quantity'];}?>">
<button type="button" onclick="saveAjaxSetting()" class="sg-main-btn sg-primary-btn" id="ajaxSubmit">Save</button>
</form>

<form action="store" method="post">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="max_accessories" name="max_accessories" value="<?php if (isset($setting['max_accessories'])){echo $setting['max_accessories'];}?>">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="max" name="max" value="<?php if (isset($setting['max'])){echo $setting['max'];}?>">
<button type="button" onclick="saveAjaxSetting()" class="sg-main-btn sg-primary-btn" id="ajaxSubmit">Save</button>
</form>
```

This is my route:-
    Route::post('/store','Crud\SettingController@saveSetting');

here is my setting controller:-

```
public function saveSetting(StoreSetting $request)
{
    try{
        //Log::info($request);
        $setting= request(['is_active','max_accessories','quick_view','accessory_discription','thumbnail','quantity_selector','addons_heading','quantity','variant','price']);

        $data= array_map(array($this,'settingData'), array_keys($setting), array_values($setting));

        $keys=array_keys($setting);
        //Log::info($data);
        if (!empty($data))
        {
            Model::whereIn('entity_name',$keys)->delete();
            $settingData= Model::insert($data);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception("Setting not saved in ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And my ajax script is:-

```
function saveAjaxSetting(data) {
console.log(data);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/spiceaddons/public/store",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "method": 'POST',
        "data": data
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        toastr.error('Error in saved');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        toastr.success(' Setting saved');

    },
});
```

}

This is all of the code is here
And
Problem:- data not insert in database.

Comment: What errors do you see? Does your ajax call complete or is there an error?

Comment: @niraj not an error in console. but data not insert in database

Comment: I would have expected at least one error as you're not sending a CSRF token in your Ajax calls, unless you've disable CSRF or have added the route to the exclude list. Are you using `$fillable` or `$guarded` in your `Model`?

Comment: @niraj yes i used in model $fillable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you but I am submitting data without {{ csrf_field() }} because I stopped middleware. and I am using the onclick event on a button so my new ajax code is here and it is work properly:-

```
<script>
    function accessorySetting() {
        var data={'max_accessories':$('input[name="max_accessories"]').val(),
                  'quick_view':$('input[name="quick_view"]:checked').val(),
                  'thumbnail':$('option:selected').val(),
                  'accessory_discription':$('input[name="accessory_discription"]:checked').val(),
                  'quantity_selector':$('input[name="quantity_selector"]:checked').val()
                };

        saveAjaxSetting(data);
    }

    function languageSetting() {
        var data={'addons_heading':$('input[name="addons_heading"]').val(),
                  'quantity':$('input[name="quantity"]').val(),
                  'variant':$('input[name="variant"]').val(),
                  'price':$('input[name="price"]').val()};
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        saveAjaxSetting(data);
    }

    function saveAjaxSetting(data1) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data1));
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/spiceaddons/public/store",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:data1,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            toastr.success("Setting Save Successfully");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            var response = JSON.parse(err.responseText);
            $.each( response.errors, function( key, value) {
                toastr.error(value);
            });

        },

    });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be number of reasons why your code isn't working.

**1 - CSRF Token**

Your API call is using POST. Assuming this route is in the `web.php` routes file, it means your form needs to include the CSRF token. To do this, add the following line to each of the HTML forms (after the opening `form` tag):

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

**2 - Fillable Fields**

If you are using `$fillable` in your Model, you need to make sure the array contains all the fields you expect. If any column is missing form the `$fillable` array, data won't be saved to that column.

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'value', ... ];
```

**3 - Check the `laravel.log` file**

Check the error log file in `storage/logs/larave.log` to see if any other errors or exceptions are being thrown by your code. This will give you a stack trace to help you which file and line could be causing the error.